# Curves automation in Adobe Photophop (CS 6)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, photoshop-scripting, automation

I have some microscopy photographs with different exposures. The grayscale images will be used for comparison next to each other. Currently, to 'normalize' the differences in the pictures I tweak the Curves while looking at the data in the Histogram tab (mean, median and standard deviation). I have quite a lot of pictures to correct, which is going to take a lot of time.

Is it possible to normalize the grays in those images using automation (actions, scripts etc)? For instance, I would select the mean gray value and standard deviation (optionally min and max), and the pictures would be adjusted.

Please let me know if such option exists. If not in PS, then perhaps in other software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using something like Matematica or Matlab for the job. Mathematica is pretty powerful [in this department](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramTransform.html) and quite easy to use.

But yes you can use *match color** it is a similar histogram matching function in Photoshop. You can save the statistics, then record a action with applying match by loading the statistics. You can then use batch processing for this.

You can also do something similar with ImageMagik like using [histmatch](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/histmatch/index.php)

* found in *Image → Adjustments → Match Color...*

Comment: Thanks for the Match Colours tip! Works like a charm with the batch processing!

Comment: The reason why i brought up Mathematica and friends is that eventually you want to do duch things as [count items](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) etc etc and mathematica will do that for you and extends easily for your entire scientific need.

Comment: That could be very useful in my research! I will look into it further. Thanks for the link!